# Getting {"error":"bad_request"} in a Python wunderlist API Task

Tags: python, post, python-requests, wunderlist

I want to create a task in python's wunderlist api, and this is my code:

```
import requests, json
access_token = "MY TOKEN"
client_id= "My Client ID"
h = {"X-Access-Token": access_token, "X-Client-ID": client_id, "Content-Type": "application/json"
da = {"list_ld": 330478059, "title": "TEST TASK"}
url= "https://a.wunderlist.com/api/v1/tasks"
r= requests.post(url, headers=h, data=da)
```

But I get "bad_request", why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in `da` that you send needs to be JSONified. Try dumping it to a string -

```
from json import dumps
r = requests.post(url, headers=h, data=dumps(da))
```

Alternatively, pass `da` directly as an argument to `json=...`, which'd automatically take care of serialisation -

```
r = requests.post(url, headers=h, json=da)
```